# Profiling C++ with Google Perf tools and Dynamic Libraries

Tags: c++, debugging, profiling

I'm trying to profile a C++ application, that I did not write, to get a sense for where the major computation points are.  I'm not a C++ expert and even less so C++ debugging/profiling expert.  I believe I am running into a (common?) problem with dynamic libraries.

I compile link to [Google CPU Profiler](http://google-perftools.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/cpuprofile.html) using (OS X, G++):

```
env LIBS=-lprofiler ./configure
make
make install
```

I then run profile the installed application (jags) with:

```
env CPUPROFILE=./jags.prof /usr/local/bin/jags regression.cmd
pprof /usr/local/bin/jags jags.prof
```

Unfortunately, I get the error:

```
pprof /usr/local/bin/jags jags.prof Can't exec "objdump": 
No such file or directory at /usr/local/bin/pprof line 2833.

objdump /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/
Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libLAPACK.dylib: No such file or directory
```

The program dynamically links to libLAPACK.dylib.  So `prof` does not seem to understand it (?).  I thought about trying to statically link, but the documents associated with the program say that it is impossible to statically link in LAPACK or BLAS (two required libraries).

Is there a way to have the profiler ignore libLAPACK?  I'm okay if it doesn't sample within libLAPACK. Or how might I get profiling to work?

Comment: I believe my problem is actually that OSX does not have the `objdump'.  It instead uses `otool'.  If anybody knows the solution, please let me know...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error was caused by jags being a shell script, that subsequently called profilable code.

```
pprof /usr/local/bin/REAL_EXEC jags.prof
```

fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a clean way to do it, but maybe there's a hacky workaround -- what happens if you hack the pprof perl script (or better a copy thereof;-), line 2834, so that instead of calling `error` it emits the message and then does `return undef;`?

Answer (score 0):

If you're profiling on OSX, the [Shark](http://developer.apple.com/tools/shark_optimize.html) tool is really great as well. It's very simple to use, and has worked out of the box for me when I've tried it.